# Windeployqt does not find all the dependencies

Tags: c++, qt

I built my Qt project in release mode and have the .exe file. I am using `Qt 5.7 32-bit for Desktop (MSVC 2015)` cmd and running `C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015\bin\windeployqt.exe my_app.exe`

However when running it, `windeployqt` does not find all the dependencies. I get this output.

```
Adding Qt5Svg for qsvgicon.dll
Direct dependencies: Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Widgets
All dependencies   : Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Widgets
To be deployed     : Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Svg Qt5Widgets
```

When I try to run the .exe file I am still missing `Qt5Network.dll`, `Qt5xml.dll`, `Qt5XmlPatterns.dll`, `Qt5WebEngineWidgets.dll`, `Qt5WebEngineCore.dll`, and `Qt5Quick.dll`. It is also missing `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll`.

In my .pro file I have `QT      += core gui xml xmlpatterns widgets webenginewidgets network`

I've been searching for a solution to this and even though I can copy paste them manually and it works or add them with -network -xml etc, I wanted to see if there was a way to add all the dependencies together.

Comment: There's still plenty of bugs like this in Qt's new deployment tools. You can file bug reports here: http://bugreports.qt.io/

Comment: Have you tried copying these DLLs manually? Having a similar problem with only the `Debug` configuration. When I have to use the debugger, thinking of manually copying the needed DLLs. Will look into filing a bug with Qt dashboard.

Comment: Manually copying the DLLS works, I run the exe and which every dll the error says I am missing I copy it and eventually it works. Since I am using this as part of a script I wanted to see if it could be automated in order to avoid further maintenance issues. Guess I'll just have to do it manually.

Comment: Till the bug is fixed, that's the only option I see available. I have the same problem only with the debug version of the latest Qt I downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

### Preamble

I think `windeployqt` doesn't try to deploy `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` for now, because they are not in `c:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\bin\` (however, they are in `c:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\opt\bin\`)

if `windeployqt` works buglessly then `windeployqt ./` deploys all Qt DLLs without any params.

Unfortunately, `windeployqt` is still buggish, because sometimes it doesn't create required and creates useless.

So you can add required ( ex. `--core`) and skip created useless (ex. `--no-svg`):

`windeployqt --compiler-runtime --core --gui --network --widgets --winextras --no-svg --no-system-d3d-compiler --no-translations --no-opengl-sw --no-angle ./`

more package_name and commands — https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html.

### Answer

You can create qmake-parser of variable QT, prepend `--` to package-names and insert to windeployqt-command:

```
DESTDIR = "path/to/dest"
QT     = core gui network widgets winextras

CONFIG( release, debug|release ) {
    PACKAGES = ""
    for(package,QT){
        PACKAGES += "--$${package} "
    }

    NO_PACKAGES = --no-svg \
        --no-system-d3d-compiler --no-translations --no-opengl-sw --no-angle

    RETURN = $$escape_expand(\n\t)

    # windeployqt
    QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$RETURN windeployqt --compiler-runtime \
        $${PACKAGES} $${NO_PACKAGES} \
        $$quote($$shell_path($$DESTDIR))

    # copy OpenSSL dlls
    OPENSSLFILES = $$shell_path($$PWD/../../bin_openssl_1.0.2h/*.dll)
    DDIR = $$shell_path($$DESTDIR)
    QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$RETURN $$QMAKE_COPY $$quote($$OPENSSLFILES) $$quote($$DDIR)
}
```